# Why can't I send file and photo in Telegram?

Tags: telegram

Telegram works fine on Windows.

I installed Telegram application in Ubuntu.

I can't send a photo or file using Telegram.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there any error message? Please describe your problem in a little more detail, what steps did you try, and where does it not work as you expect?

Comment: every thing works fine.but when i dragged the   photo  into telegram chart and clicked on send .but   it didn't  not upload. i installed this application with terminal and telegram is  in      /opt/telegram

Comment: post op of the cmd *ls -lhtd /opt/telegram/* and *ls -lht /opt/telegram*

Comment: ok i have a bigger problem i cant upload file and photo in any application.
including Firefox.

Comment: Telegram  telegram.svg  Updater
@SAGARBHOOSHAN

Comment: Unless you explain the problem in detail or post some screenshots or details of the error thrown we can't help you out. Well did you try a reboot since its affected your whole system ?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but if the issue keeps reoccurring to a point where rebooting or logging out and back in all the time becomes too inconvenient, I can recommend the `telegram-purple` package from `ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8` in combination with either Pidgin or Telepathy.

Answer (score 5):

Your Telegram app probably doesn't have access to your storage. Go to the Telegram settings , then go to the permissions and turn storage access on .
And if the options aren't available in telegram, then open Ubuntu Software centre and access the permission list from there.
in recent updates this is the procedure to be followed

Comment: Or got Ubuntu Software > Telegram > Permissions, give access to removable media

Answer (score 3):

The telegram-desktop snap needs the `removable-media` connection. Therefore, you'll need to run (you'll be prompted for Sudo access as well):

```
snap connect telegram-desktop:removable-media
```

The command above works in Linux Mint as well.